# jq 1.5 match a record where 2 or more keys match names and values

Tags: json, bash, jq

Not quite sure how to ask the question clearly but, given a recursive structure as below. How would I use `walk` to match 2 or more key strings to values. I will not know where in the structure the result will be. It could be the top level or 10 levels deep.

```
"children": {
    "ccc": [{
        "id": "ddd",
        "des": "object d",
        "parent": "ccc",
        "other": "zzz"
    },{
        "id": "zzz",
        "des": "object z",
        "parent": "ccc",
        "other" : "ddd"
  }]
}
```

I would like to find a record where `key=id=ddd` && `key=parent=ccc`I would then like to add a new key/value to that record. Using `.key|match("")` will give me a match to the value of the key but not the key name itself. So searching for `ddd` may match both `id` and `other`.

I have tried several combos and if doing in bash it would look something like

match_criteria

```
     ((.key|match("id") and (.key|test("ddd")) 
        and 
     ((.key|match("parent") and (.key|test("ccc"))
```

new_key_value

```
+= {"newkey":"newValue"}
```

insert match statement into

```
walk(if type == "object"
      then
        with_entries(if ..match_criteria.. )
      then ..new_key_value.. else . end)
```

so the result should look like

```
"children": {
    "ccc": [{
        "id": "ddd",
        "des": "object d",
        "parent": "ccc",
        "other": "zzz",
        "newkey": "newValue"
    },{
        "id": "zzz",
        "des": "object z",
        "parent": "ccc",
        "other":"ddd"
  }]
}
```

**UPDATE**
based on feedback in the answer from @peak i have updated the code as follows

```
jsonOut=$(jq 'walk(when(type == "object";
              with_entries(
                  when(any(.value[]; .id == "ddd");
                           .value[] += {"newkey": "newValue"}
                            ))))' <<< ${jsonIn})
```

unfortunately this still leaves two open issues

a) this code adds `{"newkey": "newValue"}` to all children where the search criteria is true, ie: to both `id:ddd` && `id:zzz`, rather than to just the `id:ddd` record

```
"children": {
        "ccc": [{
            "id": "ddd",
            "des": "object d",
            "parent": "ccc",
            "other": "zzz",
            "newkey": "newValue"
        },{
            "id": "zzz",
            "des": "object z",
            "parent": "ccc",
            "other":"ddd",
           "newkey": "newValue"
      }]
    }
```

b) adding multiple section criteria to the `any` clause. I have tried using the `AND` or `|` joining methods but this throws errors.

```
when(any(.value[]; .id == "ddd" | .other == "zzz"); //no match, no value added
or
when((any(.value[]; .id == "ddd") AND (any(.value[]; .other == "zzz"));
     //error : unexpected ')', expecting $end
or
when(any(.value[]; .id == "ddd", .other == "zzz"); //no match, no value added
```

Can you advise the syntax for both issues.

**UPDATE2** Understanding the `when` filter a littler better, I have now nested these and it seems to work in narrowing the result set. However problem `a)` updating both records when a match is true still exists.

```
jsonOut=$(jq 'walk(when(type == "object";
          with_entries(
                       when(any(.value[]; .id == "ddd");
                        when(any(.value[]; .other == "zzz");
                            .value[] += {"newkey": "newValue"}
                            )))))' <<< ${jsonIn})
```

jsonIn

```
{"children": {
    "ccc": [{
        "id": "ddd",
        "des": "object d",
        "parent": "ccc",
        "other": "zzz"
    },{
        "id": "zzz",
        "des": "object z",
        "parent": "ccc",
        "other":"ddd"
  }],
  "www": [{
        "id": "ddd",
        "des": "object d",
        "parent": "www",
        "other": "ppp"
   },{
        "id": "kkk",
        "des": "object z",
        "parent": "www",
        "other":"ddd"
  }]
}}
```

jsonOut

```
{
    "children": {
        "ccc": [{
            "id": "ddd",
            "des": "object d",
            "parent": "ccc",
            "other": "zzz",
            "newkey": "newValue"
        }, {
            "id": "zzz",
            "des": "object z",
            "parent": "ccc",
            "other": "ddd",
            "newkey": "newValue" <=need to NOT add this entry
        }],
        "www": [{
            "id": "ddd",
            "des": "object d",
            "parent": "www",
            "other": "ppp"
        }, {
            "id": "kkk",
            "des": "object z",
            "parent": "www",
            "other": "ddd"
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a response to the "UPDATED" question:

```
walk(when(type == "object";
          with_entries(when(.key|test("ccc");
                            .value |= map( when(.id=="ddd";
                                      . + {"newkey": "newValue"}))))))
```

#### p.s.

In future, please follow the mcve guidelines: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: can you explain what part of mcve i missed. I feel I followed the guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to use `walk` here is to include the update in the "then" part of the `if ... then ... else ...end`.  To emphasize and clarify this, and to shorten the solution, I'll use the generic helper function, `when`:

```
def when(filter; action): if (filter?) // null then action else . end;
```

The solution to the problem can now be written in a very straightforward way:

```
walk(when(type == "object";
          with_entries(when(.key|test("ccc");
                       when(any(.value[]; .id == "ddd");
                            .value += ["ADDITIONAL"])))))
```

Of course you might want a fancier test than .id == "ddd", and you might want to perform the update only once per "ccc" object, but the same structure would be used.

In reality, you might also want to wrap the above expression in a `def` so it can more readily be parameterized and maintained.

Comment: thanks @peak, can you explain the `any(.value[];` part. is this evaluating  that only next level child element matches or will it also keep recusing down until it finds it through nested levels?

Comment: any/2 is documented in the manual and elsewhere. It simply checks whether the condition is true for any item in the given stream, here .value[]

Comment: peak I have updated the question to reflect your comment `update only once per "ccc" object` as I have not been able to achieve this OR the multiple selection criteria using `any`