# jq save value of nested key into var

Tags: json, bash, jq

With thanks to @peak with the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49132181/jq-1-5-match-a-record-where-2-or-more-keys-match-names-and-values) I have started to understand jq, but I am struggling with the basics of how to capture the output to vars in bash. reviewing the jq manual has not cleared things up

given the json below I would like to use walk to capture the value of a nested key. The structure is unknown prior to execution, so a standard query is not possible and the needed key can be a arbitrary nested level deep from 0 to 20.

sample json

```
{
    "zzz": [{
        "id": "aaa",
        "des": "object A",
        "parent": "zzz",
        "children": {
            "aaa": [{
                "id": "bbb",
                "des": "object B",
                "parent": "aaa",
                "children": {
                    "bbb": [{
                        "id": "ccc",
                        "des": "object C",
                        "parent": "bbb",
                        "children": {
                            "ccc": [{
                                "id": "ddd", <===this is the value I need
                                "des": "object d",
                                "parent": "ccc"
                            }]
                        }
                    }, {
                        "id": "eee",
                        "des": "object e",
                        "parent": "bbb"
                    }]
                }
            },{
                "id": "fff",
                "des": "object f",
                "parent": "aaa"
            }]
        }
    }]}
```

now using the `walk` function I can locate the key I want

```
myId=$(jq 'walk(when(type == "object";
                            with_entries(
                            when(.key|test("ccc");
                            when(any(.value[]; .parent == "ccc");
                                ...insert action-code here....
                                )))))' <<< ${json})
```

If I use the `walk` code above and have an action code like `.value[] += {"myKey": "myVal"}` it will add it to the selected object.

Now I want to capture the value of `id` not add to the object. So I though it would be a simple string or perhaps a select statement but they do not work.

action-code

```
select(.parent == "ccc")|.hrn|.value
or
.hrn.value
or
.value[].hrn?
```

plus a lot of other combinations. What is the correct syntax to capture the `id` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this type of problem, you can use `..`.  With your data as input, the following filter:

```
..
| objects
| to_entries[]
| select(.key|test("ccc"))
| .value[]
| select(.parent=="ccc")
| .id
```

produces:

```
"ddd"
```

Comment: thanks for the clarification. Where in the manual should I have noticed the difference between using `walk` and the standard `pipe` method in your answer for read vs insert? It is not clear to me when one method should be used over another.